# What to do if operations after Mongoose findOneAndUpdate fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema that has a property which is an array of `ObjectId` child documents.

If one of those child documents needs to be removed/deleted, of course I want to remove it from the parent's array property.

The question I have is: **In what order do I perform the remove/delete operation for the child, and the findOneAndUpdate operation for the parent?**

The reason I ask is that if I remove/delete the child first, successfully, but then have an error removing that `ObjectId` from the parent's array property, it will seem like the child still exists under the parent.

However if I remove the `ObjectId` from the parent first, and then have an issue removing/deleting the child, I don't think there's a way to revert the parent back to before removing that `ObjectId`, and I'd rather not have orphaned documents hanging around, if I can help it.

What I've come up with at this point feels "hacky", and could in turn produce its own errors:

```js
  async deleteForm(req,res,next) {
    let currentLocation;
    try {
      //Remove the reference to the Form from the 'forms' array in the parent 'Location'
      try {
        currentLocation = await Location.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            forms: mongoose.types.ObjectId(req.params.formId)
          }, 
          {
            $pull: {forms: req.params.formId}
          }
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        throw new Error('Error removing Form from Location')
      }

      //Actually find and remove the 'Form' itself
      try {
        await Form.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.formId);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        /* If the 'Form' can't be removed, re-add the reference to the form back into the 
         parent 'Location's 'forms' array*/
        await currentLocation.update({
          $push: {forms: mongoose.types.ObjectId(req.params.formId)}
        })
        throw new Error('Error deleting Form')
      }

    } catch (err) {
      req.session.error = err;
    } finally {
      res.redirect(`/locations/${currentLocation._id}`);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Aviv Lo for reminding me that callbacks and `Promise.then()` are a thing. I honestly feel so new every time I post a question.

Here's what I ended up with:

```js
async deleteForm(req,res,next) {
    let currentLocation;
    try {
      //Find the parent location, to be updated after deleting the form
      try {
        currentLocation = await Location.findOne(
          {
            forms: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.formId)
          }
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        throw new Error('Error removing Form from Location')
      } 

      //Actually find and remove the 'Form' itself
      try {
        new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          try {
            await Form.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.formId);
            resolve();
          } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
        })
        /* only after the form is deleted, remove the reference from the parent 
        Location */
        .then(async () => {
          await currentLocation.update({
            $pull: {forms: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.formId)}
          });
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);        
        throw new Error('Error deleting Form')
      }
      req.session.success = 'Form deleted!'
    } catch (err) {
      req.session.error = err;
    } finally {
      res.redirect(`/locations/${currentLocation._id}`);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first run a delete operation against the child document, and then run an update operation against the parent doc. If you're using callbacks, you can nest the 2nd operation under the `.then` block of the 1st operation, so that you can guarantee the child doc. is deleted before updating the parent doc.

Comment: If I don't want to use callbacks, could I maybe wrap the `Form` delete method in a promise, and then use `Promise.then()` to update the `Location`?

Comment: Yes. As long as there is a `.then()` the promise will have to be resolved first before the code in the block can be executed. It potentially solves your issue.